# Register Multiple People for Multiple Paid Events With Webform

Tags: civievent, webform-civicrm

I am trying to create a CiviCRM Webform where the user can select multiple events to come to for multiple people in the same form.  I have it working great that the user fills out the information and clicks the events that they want to attend and their guests.

Each event costs $10.  I am trying to add up all of the events selected on the Webform and then have the user checkout with the correct price. For example someone may select 5 total events to attend so they should be charged $50.

Is this something that can be done with Webform without custom development?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do this with webform civicrm; check out the screenshots I posted in response to a similar question by Naomi - not too long ago.

Comment: - I found the response  (http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/13129/webform-event-fees-in-combination).  I am very unsure how you got from step two to three.  I have I have five events available with checkboxes but I do not have the  hidden price fields.  Tanks for the help!

Comment: If you check the box for participant fee in Step 1 you'll het a webform element - that you can then edit that element to add the $ amount for that event in Step 2; Step 3 is the result of configuring Step 2 correctly;

Comment: Karin,  I sincerely appreciate your help.  I am missing something here so I hope you will bear with me.  First of all one thing, I think I am doing differently is that I have five events possible for each participant.  When I try and let the parent select the event I only get one price field.  I am unsure how to set the price field for each event.  I do not see a way to have selections instead of one. If you can point me to what I am missing I would really appreciate it.  - Thanks, Steve.

Comment: Hey Steve: note in step 1 - screenshot: Number of Event sets per participant - I've got 2 for you make that 5;

Comment: I tried this.  If I make it 5 and then have "User Select" for all 5 I get five lists of five events.  If I choose one event then the person registering is automatically registered for all five  events.  I do not know why I am having so much trouble with this.  -Steve

Comment: I figured it out. I will document in full what I was doing wrong so other have this too.